# ModelMapper fail validation when types don't match exactly

Tags: java, modelmapper

I've just noticed my two classes had slightly different types for the same property, double vs Double. As a result null Double would be automatically be converted to 0 double. Now I see I could even have the same property defined as a String on one side without any validation errors being raised.

Is there a configuration in ModelMapper to require strict type mapping between properties, ie. fail validation if the types are not exactly the same.

Example:

```
public class MyCarDto {
    public double numberOfWheels;
}

public class MyCarDao {
    public Double numberOfWheels;
}

public class MyCarMapper {
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public MyCarMapper() {
        modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.typeMap(MyCarDto.class, MyCarDao.class);

        // should throw an exception saying property numberOfWheels should be exact same type
        modelMapper.validate();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I hope you know that there is a difference between `double` and `Double` and I don't mean the `d/D`.

Comment: Yes, which is why I would like a validation error when my DTO/DAO are not fully matched wrt double vs Double.

Comment: `Double` is able to hold NULL, `double` not. `Double` is an object, `double` is not an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure full type matching](https://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/config/Configuration.html#setFullTypeMatchingRequired-boolean-).

```java
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setFullTypeMatchingRequired(true);
```

Comment: This works for a double vs String mismatch. Is there a way to make it also work for a double vs Double mismatch?